# Apache Rewrite Directory Index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Basically, if the user agent string contains something then I want DirectoryIndex to be ignored. This doesn't appear to work at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "DirectoryIndex to be ignored"? You obviously can't just ignore it but you can take steps to bypass what it does. Do you have examples of behavior you want when the user agent contains "Kodi"?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is when looking at the above directory index I have, I only want the "/_h5ai/server/php/index.php" part to take effect on non "Kodi" user-agent strings.

Comment: *I only want the "/_h5ai/server/php/index.php" part to take effect on **non** "Kodi" user-agent strings.*, the condition you have in your htaccess file does the complete opposite.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that's the case. I know I am wrong but the way I see it it's checking for Kodi agent string and then rewriting the "/_h5ai/server/php/index.php" request to /

Comment: That rule is applied before a directory index is chosen, and the h5ai directory index will only ever be used if the directory doesn't contain a index.html or index.php. You can't arbitrarily ignore parts of the DirectoryIndex directive

Comment: AH I see, I did not realize it was applied before. So then it is not possible to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Kodi [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ /_h5ai/server/php/index.php [L,QSA]
```